# Accessing array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, object, doctrine

I am using Doctrine (DQL) with ZF2 to perform the following query:

```
$qb->select('a.schoolID, a.schoolName')
    ->from('College\Entity\School', 'a');
$schools=$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This returns and array of objects or a two dimensial Array as such:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
    'schoolID' => int 1
    'schoolName' => string 'Alabama A & M University' (length=24)
1 => 
   array (size=2)
    'schoolID' => int 2
    'schoolName' => string 'University of Alabama at Birmingham'
```

My question is: How and What's the best approach to access an Array of this type with unknown numbers of objects in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean? It's a plain array.

You can, for example, loop through it like:

```
foreach ($schools as $school)
{
   // Do something with $school, like:
   echo $school['schoolName'];
}
```

You can query the number of items like `count($schools)`.

Comment: You are right. I think I was looking at it on a whole different way. This approach should work. Thanks!